# Trying to get Boolean values by using identity operator in print statement. But it is giving me wrong values how to solve it?

Tags: python, operators

```
a = 'Hello'

b = 4.3

c = print("a" is str and "b" is float)
```

I've done it this way - is this correct?

```
a = 6
b = "hello"

print (type(a) is int and type(b)is str)
```

I got true here..

Comment: Assigning `print(anything_inside)` to a variable would in turn make that variable `NoneType`.

Comment: The operator you need is 'if'.

Comment: Do you want to print `True` if variable `a` is string and variable `b` is float? If yes, you can use `print(isinstance(a, str) and isinstance(b, float))` -> This prints `True`

Comment: @AndrejKesely , that is a good answer, i'd upvote it, i think it helps.

Comment: Thank You @AndrejKesely  I got my concept clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the superfluous quotes:

```
a = 'Hello'
b = 4.3
print(type(a) is str and type(b) is float)
```

output:

```
True
```

You can also use `isinstance()`:

```
a = 'Hello'
b = 4.3
print(isinstance(a, str) and isinstance(b, float))
```

output:

```
True
```

Comment: Yes i wanted this.. But what is isinstance ? i don't know.. can you explain me.. AS i m currently learning python.

Comment: Please let me know if the documentation is unclear about `isinstance()` : https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#isinstance 
Would you accept the answer since it's what you expected?

Comment: You have to click on the left of the answer (next to Up/Down arrows) to __mark__ it as accepted.
`hello` is a variable unless you surround it with quotes as in `"hello"`, and `4.3` is not an type `int` but `float`.

Comment: `=` is an **assignment** operator in Python, not a test of equality. You will never get a `True` by assigning `str` to a variable, or `float`. If you mean `a == str`, you will not get a `True` either. Think of `str` as a __class__ in OOP. The variable `a` can be an __instance__ of this class, but not the class itself. This is the reason why `isinstance()` exists. The same goes for `float`, of course.